# Installing MySQL with Macports on Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, macports

I am following [this tutorial](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP) **Step 3 (Install MySQL)** but it's failing. I am running Mac OS X Yosemite and have freshly installed Macports 2.3.3-10.10.

`sudo port install mysql51-server` failed with ["All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable..."](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/45677) so I ran `sudo port install mysql56-server` instead which seemed OK.

1) Then this works:

```
$ sudo port select mysql mysql56
Selecting 'mysql56' for 'mysql' succeeded. 'mysql56' is now active.
```

2a) But the next instruction fails:

```
$ sudo -u _mysql mysql_install_db5
sudo: mysql_install_db5: command not found
```

2b) The guide says "If that fails to work, then try this:" but it fails too:

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db5 
sudo: mysql_install_db5: command not found
```

3) Loading the port appears to work:

```
sudo port load mysql56-server
```

4) But I cannot connect to mysql:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql56/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

How can I get this running? Is there an equivalent to steps 2a / 2b for MySQL 5.6? Maybe I'm just missing the required paths given that I'm getting `command not found`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check for permissions problems?

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /opt/local/var/db/mysql56/
```

Anyway, this seems a defect in the [port](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/44496).

I would attempt to install [a previous version of MySQL](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MySQLWorkbench).